# enctype="multipart/form-data" destroying linebreaks?

Tags: php, forms

I have a simple, php-generated form submitted with multipart/form-data (because I need some upload-fields, this is just a simple example to show the problem):

```
print '<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
print '<input type="Hidden" name="test" value="Line'."\n".'Break">';
print '<button type="submit">Submit</button>';
print '</form>';
```

As you can see, there is a \n linebreak in the data.

Posting the form, I get this string for $_POST["test"] (tested with Chrome, FF and IE on Win7):

```
0:L 76
1:i 105
2:n 110
3:e 101
4: 13
5: 10
6:B 66
7:r 114
8:e 101
9:a 97
10:k 107
```

As you can see, the \n linebreak (= 10) has been converted to a \r\n linebreak (= 13 10).

Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: might want to look into `heredoc` for repeating `print`

Comment: Are you on Windows? http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html

Comment: Thanks for your replys.

@Andrew: As statet this is just an example, and for better reading I broke the lines appart.

Comment: @Chris85: Yes Windows. I know the difference, but the problem occurs when transferring binary data in a form with multipart/form-data.

Comment: Actually the `multipart/form-data` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: you might want to check this, [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br)

Comment: @Flosculus: You are right. Hm. It made a difference using a ajax-call... (thats where the problem is from)

Comment: Hm, the linebreak is converted on linux-systems as well.

Comment: Browsers need to be compatible with all operating systems.  Linux uses `\n` and Windows uses `\r\n`.  However most programs recognise `\r\n` as a valid new line symbol and treat it accordingly.  There is nothing you can do about it.  The reason this is a problem "for you" is because you are using new lines in a form field which typically holds a single line value.  For example you wouldn't normally perform a string comparison on a `textarea`, but you would on a ~10 character hidden input.

Comment: Yes the problem is I need to transfer binary data throug a form, with always replacing \n with \r\n I just can't do this, I guess I have to do some encoding like base64_encode before.

Comment: Then `base64_encode` the data before printing it to the form.